# get value from input on button click and enter key press react

Tags: reactjs, input

I have a react component

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Input.module.css';
import PlayCircleFilledWhiteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/PlayCircleFilledWhite';

export const Input = ({ trackHandler }) => {
    
    const handleTrack = (e) => {
        if(e.key === 'Enter') {
            trackHandler(e.target.value);
            e.target.value = '';
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className = {classes.forma}>
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    maxLength = '30' 
                    placeholder = 'Enter tracker name' 
                    onKeyPress = {e => handleTrack(e)} 
                    className = {classes.inputText}
                />
                <PlayCircleFilledWhiteIcon className = {classes.btnSubmit}/>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Function `trackHandler` pass the value from input to another component.
I need to pass this value in two ways: by press key 'Enter' on keyboard or click on button. I've realised first way but I need to create both of them.
Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this. Use `useState` hook to store the input value and create a common function which will be called on button click and on enter key press.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./style.css";

const Input = ({}) => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState("");

  const handleTrack = () => {
    if (val.length !== 0) {
      // Do something with value
      console.log("got this:", val);
    }
  };

  const handleKeyPress = e => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      handleTrack();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={val}
        onChange={e => {
          setVal(e.target.value);
        }}
        onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
      />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          handleTrack();
        }}
      >
        Click
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Input />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vane9t

Answer (score 1):

You can use useRef as ref property on input.

```
const inputRef = useRef(null)
```

Then you get access to input value something like this:

```
inputRef.target.value
```

If this not work for first you should log the inputRef to the console which is the exact property what you need.